# Polymer update object outside of component and reflect changes to UI

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Is it possible to reflect changes to polymer component property without update the value via `.set(path, value)`.

For example I have object with overrided setter which based on this value apply new value to other field.

```
Polymer({
        is: 'x-element',
        properties: {
            form: {type: Object,
            value: {
                     set name(v) {
                             this._name = v;
                             this.additional = v; // change the different property
                     },
                     get name() {
                             return this.name;
                     },

                     set additional(v) {
                             // process v
                             this._additional = v; // field does not reflect 
                     },
                     get additional() {
                             return this._additional;
                     }

          },
         reflectToAttribute: true
         }               
        })
```

Comment: Why not create a function that you can call on the component that sets the value for you?

Comment: This object is modified outside of element context to use this behaviour of setting another value.

Comment: You can call an element's function from outside the element's context - Keep the object in the element.